# Excel VBA: Limiting the records returned by autofilter range to at most 10 records

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I'm trying to limit the number of records returned by an autofilter to at most 10 records.

Here is the code I tried:

```
Set ws4 = Workbooks("myfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

ws4.AutoFilterMode = False
x="test"
ws4.Range("A1:BV794742").AutoFilter Field:=74, Criteria1:="=" & x & "*", Operator:=xlAnd

visibleRowCount = ws4.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

copiedRowsCount = WorksheetFunction.Min(maxRowsToCopy, visibleRowCount)

Set copyRange = ws4.AutoFilter.Range.Resize(copiedRowsCount ).SpecialCells(12)
```

I have this code as part of a loop.  In the first loop, one record is returned initially and the code works correctly.  In the second loop, more than 10 records are returned initially.  But, when I restrict it to the 10 records, copyRange only has 1 record.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Your issue here is using `.Resize`, similarly to using the `.Offset` to a filtered range, like [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976720/how-to-select-a-range-after-filtering), you'll end up Resizing from the row you start on regardless of the rows being hidden or not. Just like in the link I provided, you'll be better off finding the start and end cell and get your range through there.